# How to add user mention to message using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am new to javascript programming and i want to add usermention to the messages using react. I don't want to use any plugin or so.

What i am trying to do?

I have a message field (input element). When user enters @ then it should open a dropdown menu with a list of users. How can i trigger opening a dropdown menu when user enters @ character?

Could someone provide insight into this. thanks.

Below is the code of what i have tried,

```
class UserMention extends React.PureComponent {
    state = {
        message: '',
    };
    const user_mention_list =  [ user1, user2,....];

    handle_input_change = (event) => {
        this.setState({
             [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
        const character = event.target.value.match(/@/) ? "true" : 
        "false";
        console.log("character", character);
     };
     render = () => {
         return {
             <input
                 name="message"
                 value={this.state.message}
                 onChange={this.handle_input_change}
                 type="text"
             />
         }
     }
}
```

So on input change i check the input field for @ character entered. then i have to open a dropdown menu with a list of users. For now i have a list of users in the variable user_mention_list.

Now wanted to know if there is any efficient way in doing this.

Comment: There are plugins like [react-mentions 0.0.0](https://signavio.github.io/react-mentions/master/) to do that. You need to use one of them unless you are trying to develop something of your own.

Comment: share more code. what have you tried so far? what are you doing in onChange? From where are you getting list of users?

Comment: @sujana Did you check the plugin I sent you?

Comment: hmm thanks but didnt want to use a plugin for that.

Comment: @sujana if you do not want to use third-party plugins, you will need to create a separate `Select` component which would be rendered whenever `character ===  'true'`. This is a lot of code to write, thus you should consider using external libraries

Comment: agree with @LiJonas here you are asking us to write a library for you. It is easier to use any existing library.

Comment: @sujana just to confirm are you after a solution on how the select functionality would work for this or more so the high level process of how to go about it ?

Comment: select functionality seems okay to implement. but not sure when this character to be set false...i realised that it should be set to false when the use types a space character and clears the @...with the above regex it is set to true always when the input has @. so the select dropdown will always be visible. wanted to know how to set this to false on entering space character even though input field has @ character. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use mention's react js library also for this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mentions

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
class UserMention extends React.PureComponent {
    state = {
        message: '',
        showModal: false
    };
    const user_mention_list =  [ user1, user2,....];

    handle_input_change = (event) => {
        this.setState({
             [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
        const character = event.target.value.match(/@/)
        if (event.target.value.includes('@') {
           this.setState({ showModal: true })
        }
     };
     render = () => {
         const { showModal } = this.state
         return {
             <div>
             { showModal && <Modal /> } <-- Render the modal here
               <input
                   name="message"
                   value={this.state.message}
                   onChange={this.handle_input_change}
                   type="text"
               />
             </div>
         }
     }
}
```